# JavaScript delay Chrome Addlistener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an backgroundscript for my Chrome Extension, which is modifying the Request-URL. It is working for me. My problem now is, that I want the addlistener to "sleep" for like 10 seconds after the if statement was successfull, and the modified URL was returned.

For example:

1. I visit a page where the condition of the if statement is fulfilled
2. URL is getting modified onBeforeRequest
3. Return URL
4. For the next 10 seconds no more URL-modifications, no matter what
   site is getting loaded
5. After 10 seconds -> Addlistener should listen again until step 1 is
   triggered again.

   I already tried to manage the 10 second delay with `setTimeout()`. But this is not possible, because the addListener Loops within itsself. Anyone some ideas how to realize the 10 second break, before modifying the next URL?

Here is my Code:

```
chrome["webRequest"]["onBeforeRequest"]["addListener"](
  function(_0xdf27x2) {
    var _0xdf27x9 = _0xdf27x2["url"]["includes"](".jpg");
    if (_0xdf27x9 == false) {
      console.log("Valid Page");

      return {
        redirectUrl: _0xdf27x2["url"] + "&token=X"
      };
    } else {
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ["*://www.host.com/*"],
    types: [
      "main_frame",
      "sub_frame",
      "stylesheet",
      "script",
      "image",
      "object",
      "xmlhttprequest",
      "other"
    ]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Is that your code? you wrote that?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I know why you are askin. But basically yes, I know the variables confusing you.